# How can I package my Perl script to run on a machine without Perl?

Tags: perl, compilation, executable, distribution

People also often ask "How can I compile Perl?" while what they really want is to create an executable that can run on machines even if they don't have Perl installed.

There are several solutions, I know of:

1. [perl2exe](http://www.indigostar.com/perl2exe.htm) of IndigoStar
   It is commercial. I never tried. Its web site says it can cross compile Win32, Linux, and Solaris.
2. [Perl Dev Kit](http://www.activestate.com/Products/perl_dev_kit/) from ActiveState. 
   It is commercial. I used it several years ago on Windows and it worked well for my needs. According to its web site it works on Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, Solaris, AIX and HP-UX.
3. [PAR](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR/) or rather [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/) that is free and open source. Based on the test reports it works on the Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, NetBSD and Solaris but theoretically it should work on other UNIX systems as well.
   Recently I have started to use PAR for packaging on Linux and will use it on Windows as well.

Other recommended solutions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to the three tools listed in the question, there's another one called [Cava Packager](http://www.cavapackager.com/) written by Mark Dootson, who has also contributed to [PAR](http://par.perl.org) in the past. It only runs under Windows, has a nice Wx GUI and works differently from the typical three contenders in that it assembles all Perl dependencies in a source / lib directory instead of creating a single archive containing everything. There's a free version, but it's not Open Source. I haven't used this except for testing.

As for PAR, it's really a toolkit. It comes with a packaging tool which does the dependency scanning and assembly of stand-alone executables, but it can also be used to generate and use so-called .par files, in analogy to Java's JARs. It also comes with [client](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Repository-Client) and [server](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Repository) for automatically loading missing packages over the network, etc. The [slides of my PAR talk](http://steffen-mueller.net/talks/appdeployment/) at [YAPC::EU](http://yapceurope.org/) 2008 go into more details on this.
There's also an active mailing list: par at perl dot org.

Comment: According to cavapack's answer and the Cava website, it now runs on Linux and OS X too.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use cava packager

Answer (score 5):

It is some time since this question was first asked, but [Cava Packager](http://www.cavapackager.com/) can currently produce executable packages for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. It is no longer Windows only.

Note: As indicated by my name, I am affiliated with Cava Packager.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Perl newbie and I just downloaded Cava Packager and that's the only one I found working. I've tried ActiveState 5.10.1005 and Strawberry Perl with PAR-Packager on Windows XP. 
pp just hangs in mid-stream and no executables created.

Cava provides the only solution to creating exe on Windows so far. Thks.

Comment: Strawberry with pp worked for me (4 years after your answer).

Answer (score -3):

You could use the `perlcc` tool that's shipped with most distributions of Perl.  I've also found both `perl2exe` and Active State's Perl Dev kit useful for shipping Perl applications.

Comment: perlcc doesn't really work, and it has been like that for a long time. PAR is the way to go.

Comment: perlcc mostly does not work (see perldoc perlcc) and has been removed from perl 5.10