# How do you build perl source code to target Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, build, compilation, exe

I've got some perl source code [here](http://www.box.net/shared/1xqg3i7ptb), how do I build it on Windows, to get a windows binary that I can work with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I compile my Perl script so it can be executed on systems without perl installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237286/how-can-i-compile-my-perl-script-so-it-can-be-executed-on-systems-without-perl-in)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77278/how-can-i-package-my-perl-script-to-run-on-a-machine-without-perl

Comment: May I remind you of [Dr Strangedupe?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found **Cava Packager** to be just what I needed.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cavapackager.com](http://www.cavapackager.com/images/homepage-image.jpg))</sub>

### How to compile Perl scripts into EXEs

Download ActivePerl 5.10 for Windows.
Install it.
Restart your PC.

Download [Cava Packager](http://www.cavapackager.com/)
Install it.
Open it.

Make a new project choosing a blank folder.

Scripts > Add..
Choose your .PL script file

Perl library > [...]
Choose "C:\Perl\bin\perl510.dll"
Add
Choose "C:\Perl\lib\"
Save

Build

Answer (score 4):

Usage of external tools normally comes with compatibility issues, random errors etc. You are better off using the inbuilt perl 'pp' tool. Install PAR::Packer (which includes the pp tool) module and then read the manual for it...
It allows you to pack your perl scripts to executables, and has options as what modules and dependencies to include, I've used it on winXP and win7 and never had an issue with any executabe produced.

[pp manual](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.008/lib/pp.pm)

Comment: How do I install "pp" or "PAR::Packer" itself? I've got ActivePerl on Windows 7. Now what?

Comment: It should be available via PPM (package perl manager, just run 'ppm' command) and then use the search function, or just run 'ppm install PAR::Packer'. I am not sure though the module is in the main cpan repository, so you might actually have to download it from cpan and install manually...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Perl Development Kit from ActiveState to "compile" your script to a .exe file. I used it to create binaries of MRTG and a couple tools more to be deployed on windows servers running as a service. There used to be another product (from IndigoStar or something) called perl2exe I think to get the same result.

Comment: There are several of them. AFAIK, PAR is the only one free and supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that [Cava Packager](http://www.cavapackager.com) also supports creating executables from Perl code on Linux and Mac OS X in addition to the original Windows version.

Note: As indicated by my name, I am affiliated with Cava Packager.

Comment: FYI, you can suggest edits to existing answers to keep them current and correct, I think that would be more appropriate here. If you have not seen it please review [the FAQ "May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Never mind, apparently this is not an appropriate edit to suggest. http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/48875